# Connecting to XML elements from java messes up everything

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just created a new project and tried to connect to UI elements from code. It worked well at first, example:

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
```

But now when I try to connect to an element like "R.id.elementid" it won't find that element. I need to use the second option that contains my package name "com.package.R.id.elementid". And when I do this it messes up all my other "R.id.elementid".

This has happened before but I have no idea how I came to a solution. I know I could just connect by "com.package.R.elementid" but I'd rather use "R.id.elementid" for everything.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have your checked your import? Is it your package `com.package.R` or `android.R`?

Comment: Try to rename ids and check again ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all imports of `android.R` from your file,
and then press `CTRL + SHIFT + O` (to organise imports)

Normally, whenever I need to use `android.R` related values, I use them directly by fully qualified path. i.e. `android.R.id.someId`.
This way android.R class doesnt get imported accidently.
This allows me to directly call `R.id.myId` from my application

Answer (score 0):

Replace `import android.R` with `import yourPackageName.R`.

Clean your project after that : **Eclipse -> Project -> Clean**